# SharePoint Work Flow -Mail mutiple list items

Tags: email, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I am creating a workflow to trigger mail to set of users in a group A when new item is added to a list X.

List X has n items and all the few columns are need to be in mail content as part of the workflow.

My work flow always mails only the top most(recent) item from the list.
Is there an option to loop through the list items in Sharepoint workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the tools you're comfortable using, this can be done within SharePoint Designer with techniques that use multiple lists, such as this one

[Create a For Each Loop for Workflows Using SharePoint Designer 2010](http://sharepointgypsy.blogspot.com/2011/11/create-for-each-loop-for-workflows.html)

But, with the use of multiple lists, this becomes fragile very quickly as the complexity of the workflow increases.

Loops are best handled by developing the workflow in Visual Studio with the standard looping actions included in the Workflow Foundation.  Here is an answer from a similar question -- I will only add that in this case the logic would be in a workflow instead of a web part.

[Can I loop a list in SharePoint with Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313629/can-i-loop-a-list-in-sharepoint-with-visual-studio)

However, a custom workflow may not be needed.  SharePoint lists can have alerts configured to notify when an item is added.  These can further be configured to send out a digest email of all items added in a specific time period.  Here is an example of sending an alert to a group

[How To Send Email Alerts From SharePoint 2010 To Distribution Lists](http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=2378)